# What is difference between UITableView methods and equivalent UITableViewDatasource methods?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

How is:

`func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell`

different from:

`func cellForRow(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell?`

I recently ran into a bug where I was extending `UITableView` to be able to iterate through rows in a given section.

```
func forRows(inSection section: Int, condition: (UITableViewCell) -> ()) {

    for row in 0..<numberOfRows(inSection: section) {
        let cell = cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: row, section: section))!

        condition(cell)
    }
}
```

^^^ does not work, the cell is nil on the last row

```
func forRows(inSection section: Int, condition: (UITableViewCell) -> ()) {

    for row in 0..<dataSource!.tableView(self, numberOfRowsInSection: section) {
        let cell = dataSource!.tableView(self, cellForRowAt: IndexPath(row: row, section: section))

        condition(cell)
    }
}
```

^^^ works. I get it, but I don't get it.

What is different internally between tableView delegate methods and their equivalent methods on the tableView itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data source is meant to **provide** cells, creating them however you want to create them. Normally this involves dequeueing reusable cells or creating new ones.

When you call `cellForRow(at indexPath: IndexPath)` on the table view, it's giving you a cell that already exists, if there is one.

Comment: And the cell returned by the `UITableView cellForRow(at:)` call is the cell the table view obtained by calling `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` on its data source.

Comment: thanks for the clarification, messed it up in the question, corrected it to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

- A *delegate* method (strictly spoken `UITableViewDataSource` is also a *delegate*) is called by the framework to ask for something or to indicate a particular stage in the workflow.
  **You must not call delegate methods by yourself**.
- A *class or instance* method can be used unconcernedly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's your specific scenario since I'd need more information but

```
func cellForRow(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell?
```

returns `nil` if the cell is not visible in the screen.
In the other method the table will "load" for you the cell at the specific index path